# Preimages of intersections/unions

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Let $f(x) = x^2$ and suppose that $A$ is the closed interval $[0, 4]$ and $B$ is the closed interval $[−1, 1]$. In this case find $f^{−1}(A)$ and $f^{−1}(B)$.

Does $f^{−1}(A\cap B) = f^{−1}(A) \cap f^{−1}(B)$ in this case?

Does $f^{−1}(A \cup B) = f^{−1}(A) \cup f^{−1}(B)$?

Comment: You should say "preimages" instead of "inverses" because in this case $f^{-1}$ doesn't denote an inverse (indeed, the function $f(x)=x^2$ on $[-1,1]$ has no inverse).

Comment: Well I think the intersections are the same but I can't seem to figure out the unions

Comment: Have you found what the sets $f^{-1}(A)$ and $f^{-1}(B)$ are?

Comment: @JessyWhite Were you happy with my answer?

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

If $F: U \rightarrow V$ and $Y \subset U$ then $f^{-1}(Y)= \{x \in U : F(x) \in Y \}$

So $f^{-1}(A)=f^{-1}([0,4])=\{x \in \mathbb{R} : x^2 \in [0,4] \}= [-2,2]$

and $f^{-1}(B)=f^{-1}([-1,1])=\{x \in \mathbb{R} : x^2 \in [-1,1] \}= [0,1]$ as complex solutions are not allowed by assumption on $f$.

Also $f^{-1}(A \cap B)=f^{-1}([0,1])=\{x \in \mathbb{R} : x^2 \in [0,1] \}= [0,1]$

and $f^{-1}(A \cup B)=f^{-1}([-1,4])=\{x \in \mathbb{R} : x^2 \in [-1,4] \}= [-2,2]$ again as complex solutions not allowed.

Therefore $f^{-1}(A) \cap f^{-1}(B)= [-2,2] \cap [0,1]=[0,1] = f^{-1}(A \cap B)$

$f^{-1}(A \cup B)=f^{-1}([-1,4])=\{x \in \mathbb{R} : x^2 \in [-1,4] \}= [-2,2] = f^{-1}(A) \cup f^{-1}(B)$

Comment: Are you happy with my answer?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

The statements $f^{-1}(A\cup B)=f^{-1}(A)\cup f^{-1}(B)$ and $f^{-1}(A\cap B)=f^{-1}(A)\cap f^{-1}(B)$ are **always** true. Also if you are dealing with infinite unions/intersections (and much more).

It can be proved on base of: $$x\in f^{-1}(U)\iff f(x)\in U$$
Prove this in general and you do not have to bother about 'cases' anymore.